# Why does the IAM admin get "Error, Access denied" upon attempting to grant listObjects to the public?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am logged into the aws console as an IAM user with the AdministratorAccess policy attached. I'm trying to grant the public read access to the entire contents of a bucket.

To do this I open the bucket and click on Permissions, and select Access Control List. I select **Public Access | Everyone**, and select **List Objects**, and click on **Save**.

I get an inline error message saying "Error, Access denied".

The browser console says

"POST https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/proxy 403 (Forbidden)"

I get the same result when I try this as the root user.

I got the same result when trying to set up a bucket policy.

Am I going about this incorrectly?

Comment: When you created the bucket, did you uncheck the option to block public policies?  It's new, and it defaults to enabled (blocking): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/block-public-access-bucket.html

Comment: @Michael, thank you, that was it. S3 is quite a beast.